# Поддержка параллельных алгоритмов стандартной библиотекой

Tags: c++, c++17

В c++17 должна появиться возможность выполнения стандартных алгоритмов, например, [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
template< class ExecutionPolicy, class RandomIt >
void sort( ExecutionPolicy&& policy, RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

в параллельном режиме, передавая соответствующий [тип политики выполнения](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t). Поддерживает ли на текущий момент какой-либо из доступных online компиляторов данный функционал?

Все попытки подключить `<execution>` пока заканчивались примерно [одинаково](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lzRdeTAIIPvgwg4j):

> ```
> fatal error: execution: No such file or directory
>  #include <execution>
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> ```

Comment: gcc - [статус](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html)

Comment: clang - [статус](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html)

Comment: @isnullxbh онлайн-сервисы нужны же.

Comment: @free_ze если даже в оффлайне таких компиляторов пока нет, что говорить об онлайне :D

Comment: @free_ze, Вы открывали ссылки? :) Какие могут быть онлайн компиляторы )

Comment: По моим наблюдениям, впереди планеты всей по фичам компиляторов обычно Clang. Увидев, что там ещё нет, в другие места я даже не стал смотреть.

Comment: @D-side речь о *"The Parallelism TS Should be Standardized"*, как я понимаю?

Comment: @alexolut да, о нём. Как минимум.

Comment: @isnullxbh кстати, полезная информация по ссылкам. Мне кажется, её надо бы добавить в описание метки [tag:c++].

Comment: @isnullxbh Разумеется. Но зачем вынуждать ищущего ходить по ссылкам, если можно написать буквами?

Comment: @alexolut, хорошая идея. Было бы неплохо указать аналогичную информацию и для msvc-компилятора. Только почему-то мне она на глаза никогда не попадалась :)

Comment: @isnullxbh если оформите ответом свои комментарии с расшифровкой, готов поставить галочку. Если есть по *msvc*, то было бы вообще супер.

Comment: @isnullxbh подумали одновременно :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Parallelism TS Should be Standardized**

[параллельные версии алгоритмов STL]

---

[N4507 - предварительная версия стандарта](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4507.pdf)

[P0024R2 - спецификация](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0024r2.html)

Статус поддержки данной фичи в *Clang*: 

https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html

[не имплементировано на данный момент]

Статус поддержки данной фичи в *GCC*:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z

[не имплементировано на данный момент]

Однако, есть готовые реализации:

1. [Lutz](http://github.com/t-lutz/ParallelSTL)
2. [Microsoft](http://github.com/t-lutz/ParallelSTL)
3. [NVIDIA](http://github.com/n3554/n3554)

Comment: А можно резюмировать словами? А то по ссылкам ходить лень, да и протухают они.

Comment: @VladD, да, конечно :)

Comment: Общее название фичи "The Parallelism TS Should be Standardized". Ну и прямую [ссылку](http://wg21.link/P0024R2) на документ можно.

Comment: @VladD слова тоже должны протухнуть в этом году :)

Comment: @alexolut: Ага, я в таких случаях дописываю обычно «На текущий момент (февраль 2017)...»

Comment: @VladD а потом 30 февраля фичу допиливают и приходится всё менять!

Comment: @alexolut: ну разе что в супервисокосный год :-D